# Neovim shows some tmux errors

Tags: neovim, tmux

I am trying to setup neovim and when I a checking health using `checkleath` I am getting following error.

**Error**

```
tmux ~
- ERROR `escape-time` (500) is higher than 300ms
  - ADVICE:
    - set escape-time in ~/.tmux.conf:
      set-option -sg escape-time 10
    - https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim#optimized-builds
- WARNING `focus-events` is not enabled. |'autoread'| may not work.
  - ADVICE:
    - (tmux 1.9+ only) Set `focus-events` in ~/.tmux.conf:
      set-option -g focus-events on
- $TERM: screen-256color
```

though I have following lines in my `~/.tmux.conf` and `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`

```
set-option -sg escape-time 10
set-option -g focus-events on
```

Comment: nvim checks runtime settings of tmux. did you change tmux settings after it started?

Comment: I restarted the tmux after making this changes. and it still shows this error